# Facebook share data-href not sharing localhost content

Tags: facebook, localhost, share, fb.ui

I am developing a website in localhost and I want to have a Facebook share button which shares a page of my website. For now the page I would like to share is only local.

The share button works fine when `href` in `FB.ui` has a public available URL. It lets me share content even whit other URLs (e.g. `dev.myapp.com/mypage`) but this content does not appear on Facebook (probably because Facebook detects that this page does not exists (yet) in the web.

Funny stuff is, if I use the Facebook share button (the one provided by facebook) the content is posted even if it is only local.

So, is there a way to share local content while we are under development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Add `localhost:xxxx` as your site URL and `localhost` as one of your
   approved app domains. You can only have 1 site URL, so you may need
   the second option if your app is in production...
2. Or create 2 apps,
   one for production and one for development, with different site URLs
   and different domains.

In both cases, you have to be on `developers.facebook.com` on your app page > settings > Add platform > website.